# How to select genes from FASTA file based on names list in CSV format?

Tags: r, dataframe, fasta

I am looking for an R solution to extract multiple sequences from a FASTA file based on a match to a list of header ID's in a separate file (.csv).

I am new to R and am trying to find a way to:
Take a file containing strings that will be in the fasta headers

header_ID_strings file looks like this:
CAP357_2030, CAP357, CAP3571, etc...

a sample of my fasta file looks like this:

```
CAP357_2030
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGG
CAP357
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
CAP3571
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_004_00001_000.2
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
CAP357_2050_013wpi_v1v3_1_047_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
```

I expect the ouput of a new FASTA file just containing the sequences of header_IDs (in .csv) and discard the others which IDs I have not provided. Thanks

Comment: I doubt if this differs from general subset question (as it's a csv file). Read file into R and subset it by values in ID column.

Comment: Can you clarify the output format, it is in one continuous string, or are there line breaks after the sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare a vector against a list of options using `filter` with `%in%`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- "CAP357_2030 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGG CAP357 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT CAP3571 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_004_00001_000.2 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT CAP357_2050_013wpi_v1v3_1_047_00002_000.4 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT"
ids_in_file <- c("CAP357_2030", "CAP357_2050_013wpi_v1v3_1_047_00002_000.4")

vec <- strsplit(dat, " ")[[1]]
df <- tibble(header_id_strings = vec[seq(1, length(vec),2)],
             sequence = vec[seq(2, length(vec),2)])

df %>%
  filter(header_id_strings %in% ids_in_file) %>%
  apply(1, paste, collapse = " ") %>%
  paste(collapse = "\n") %>%
  cat()
```

gives:

```
CAP357_2030 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGG
CAP357_2050_013wpi_v1v3_1_047_00002_000.4 GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
```

Comment: I'm happy to be corrected if there is a better way to split the string up into a 2 column df!

Comment: Hi Thanks I just solved it like this 
    down=read.csv("down.csv")
    up=read.csv("up.csv")

    library("seqinr")
    allgene<- read.fasta(file = "gene.fa", 
                       seqtype = "DNA",as.string = TRUE)
    downregulated=allgene[names(allgene) %in% down$gene_id]
    upregulated=allgene[names(allgene) %in% up$gene_id]

Comment: No problems, please [up-vote and accept](//https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you think it is the best solution for your problem.